# How to find duplicated strings which appear more than once in a file

Tags: tcl

I have following code to print string which appears more than once in the list

```
set a [list str1/str2 str3/str4 str3/str4 str5/str6]
foreach x $a {
  set search_return [lsearch -all $a $x]
  if {[llength $search_return] > 1} {
   puts "search_return : $search_return"
  }
}
```

I need to print str3/str4 which appears more than once in the list

Answer (score 1):

The canonical methods of doing this are with arrays or dictionaries, both of which are associative maps. Here's a version with a single loop over the data using a dictionary (it doesn't know the total number of times an item appears when it prints, but sometimes just knowing you've got a multiple is enough).

```
set a [list str1/str2 str3/str4 str3/str4 str5/str6]

# Make sure that the dictionary doesn't exist ahead of time!
unset -nocomplain counters
foreach item $a {
    if {[dict incr counters $item] == 2} {
        puts "$item appears several times"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use an array to do something like that, since arrays have unique keys:

```
set a [list str1/str2 str3/str4 str3/str4 str5/str6]
foreach x $a {
  incr arr($x)   ;# basically counting each occurrence
}

foreach {key val} [array get arr] {
  if {$val > 1} {puts "$key appears $val times"}
}
```